# Adding API code in a basic Google Bar Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have a basic google chart:-

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic'],
    ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478],
    ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079],
    ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327]
  ]);

// Create and draw the visualization.
      new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
      );
}
```

​
I want to be able to specify the border color and width etc.
Can you tell me how to use the API commands:-
backgroundColor.stroke,
backgroundColor.strokeWidth,

i.e How do I add these API calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can send the settings for both the `stroke` color and `strokeWidth` with the rest of you options, similar to how you've specified the title for the `hAxis`:

```
backgroundColor: {
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: '2'
}
```

That would give the chart a black 2pixel border, demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/enDGt/1/).